# Oneplus 3 - Oneplus3 randomly shutdown with glitches in screen

Tags: stock-android, unbricking, oneplus-3

My oneplus 3 got this problem from last 2 days, i have unbrick my phone with `Magic Unbrick tool for oneplus3`. Even after that problem still persists
.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Unbrick Phone with mega unbrick tool for oneplus 3.

Step 2: After unbrick, start phone normal, if problem still persist, download lastest rom from oneplus store.

Step 3: Flash latest rom to oneplus device with side load.

Hope this works for you too!